# Tfs 2017 patch version

Tags: tfs, version, patch

I have applied v12 patch to our tfs 2017 v3.1 installation 15.117.27414.0. Why does the patch version not get shown in the tfs gui or in the tfs admin console ?
I was expecting to see 15.117.30801.0 but it still shows 15.117.27414.0. Can anyone explain, thank you

Answer (score 0):

15.117.30801.0 is the version of file `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Admin.dll`. If the installation of TFS 2017 Update 3.1 Patch 12 is successful, you'll see the version of file `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Admin.dll` is 15.117.30801.0. TFS 2017 is installed to `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0` by default, the file `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Admin.dll` is in `[TFS_INSTALL_DIR]\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Admin.dll`.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?